# echo image caption

Tags: post-meta, twitter-bootstrap, images, captions

I am attempting to echo out my image captions in a Bootstrap Carousel. I have managed to get my images to display but unable to display my captions. I have attempted to use wp_get_attachment_metadata however nothing is being echoed out.

Here is the code I’m using.

```
<?php 

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => ASC,
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);

?>
```

```
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                <?php $i=0; foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { $imageInfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full'); $imageCap = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment->ID) ?> 
                <div class="item <?php if ($i == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?> "> <img src="<?php echo $imageInfo[0]; ?>"/> 
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4><?php echo $imageCap->caption;?></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve caption of image correct format is

```
 <?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ); ?> 

<?php

function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
    return array(
        'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ),
        'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,
        'description' => $attachment->post_content,
        'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),
        'src' => $attachment->guid,
        'title' => $attachment->post_title
    );
}

$at= wp_get_attachment($post_thumbnail_id);
print_r($at);//show array of all image detail like title , caption etc

?>
```

Comment: Could you possibly show me how I’d incorporate that into my code? Thank you for the help

Comment: in first line of code place <?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); ?> //post id of your blog

Comment: put this code in end of my code to print img echo '<img href="'.$at['href'].'" src="'.$at['src'].'  />'; //alt="'.$at['caption'].'"